# How to deploy war file in openshift

Tags: java, cloud, server

I've created account in openshift.
I've selected tomcat7.

Then I'm trying to configure the application, This is asking public url path.

I've given application name is "**natsample**" and it is asking namespace, I tried lots of names but it is showing Namespace 'example' is already in use. Please choose another.

It doesn't take any values in namespaces.

What is the problem in this?

Answer (score 0):

The names your are trying may be very popular. This has nothing to do with `deploy war file` .

`Namespace` need to be unique across the `openshift` doamin. This namespace will be treated as an `external url (public)` from your application, that's why this is important.

If you want to host an java web application then there are lot of guide you can find for that purpose try to follow one of them. as for example:

[Tomcat-getting-started](https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-getting-started.html)

I use this one

[openshift-tomcat-quickstart](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-tomcat-quickstart)